# Text-centred shape in PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have been trying to generate shapes with text at their centres, along the lines of:

```
$pdf->Text(25, 100, 'Name', false, false, true, 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ellipse(25, 100, 20, 10);
```

But the output is completely wrong, with the text positions in a completely different location to the ellipse. Can anyone suggest a good approach to getting the shape and test centred to the same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdf->Text(25, 100, 'Name', false, false, true, 0, 0, 'C');
```

`Text` is actually a wrapper to `Cell`, temporarily changing the text rendering parameters and moving to the specified co-ordinates before calling it. There are in fact three alignment parameters to `Text` and/or `Cell`.
`$align` (set to 'C' in the question) sets the horizontal alignment of the text within the cell, but doesn't change the start position of the cell. The problem with this is that Cell is called with width 0, which extends the cell to the right margin. Centring the text thus moves the text away from the intended location.
`$calign` sets the vertical alignment of the cell relative to the given x,y location, and `$valign` sets the vertical alignment of the text within the cell.

One way to get centred text is to call `Cell` directly and create a box of known dimensions (e.g., matching the dimensions of the shape), positioned to match the centre of the shape, and centre the text within the cell with `$align` and `$valign`. For instance:

```
$cx = 50;
$cy = 100;
$rx = 20;
$ry = 10;
$pdf->SetXY($cx-$rx, $cy-$ry);
$pdf->Cell(2*$rx, 2*$ry, 'Name', null, null, 'C', null, null, null, null, 'T', 'C');
$pdf->Ellipse($cx, $cy, $rx, $ry);
```